# Setting maximum results' number via FEM

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

I am running some queries via FileNet API (Java), but I always obtain exactly 20.000 results. I suspect that there is a limit in the number of returned results by default. Is there a way to change it via FEM, if that is the case? I searched through the properties of the Object Store, but I found nothing.

Comment: if im not mistaken this is either an object store or domain setting. If you want all results, modify the javacode to turn the boolean continuable to true on the fetchrows or fetchobject function. This will allow the connection to get more pages. Obviously you need to take server resources into concideration when doing this.

Comment: Thank you Robert, I've also tried by investigating the Domain's properties, but I found nothing. I will try by setting the query as continuable if I couldn't end up with a setting via FEM. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by the `QueryCountMaxSize` and `QueryCountDefaultSize` configuration properties of the `Server Cache` subsystem. It is configurable on the domain level (root node in `FEM`):

[image: Domain Properties]
[image: Server Cache Configuration]