# How to get the count of documents for the object store using FileNet API's

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, filenet-cpe

I have more than a million documents in object store, and I want to know the count of documents for a specific time period. How can I get the count using FileNet CE api's

The code I use is below, which gives me only a maximum of 200 documents.

```
--Code
SearchScope scope= new SearchScope(obj);
SearchSQL sql= new SearchSQL();
sql.setMaxRecords(100000);
String query="select * from document where datecreated >(date)";
RepositoryRowSet res= scope.fetchRows(sql,1000,null,null);
int count=0;
PageIterator p= result.pageIterator();
while(p.nextPage){
count+=p.getElementCount();a
}
```

Comment: If maximum result number is the issue, please, consider this also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311405/setting-maximum-results-number-via-fem

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `COUNT()` function in [background searches](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.5.x?topic=guide-queries#query_concepts__background_searches):

```
select COUNT(Id) from Document
```

[Link to SQL syntax for background search query](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.5.x?topic=reference-relational-queries#query_sql_syntax_rel_queries__background_search_query_syntax)

[Working with background search queries via API](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.2.1?topic=queries-working-background-search)

Or, you can use a direct database connection and find the count of documents using documented database tables schema from DocVersion table.

[Table schema - DocVersion](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.2.1?topic=reference-object-store-table-schemas#database_table_schemas__docversion_table)